# Installing gevent on Centos error gcc

Tags: python, gcc, centos

I've installed all the requirements (I think) but I still get errors when running

```
pip install gevent
```

I've also tried installing from github with the same error below:

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/gev
ent/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n
', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-vKU7TO-record/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_
root/gevent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 185,
in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 16
1, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 30: ordinal not in r
ange(128)
```

I'm not sure what other information would be useful, let me know.

Answer (score 7):

In case you still need an answer, installing libevent-devel and python-devel fixes this.

```
yum install libevent-devel
yum install python-devel
```

Comment: I think you mean `yum install python-devel`

Answer (score 3):

Using yum solved this error for me.

```
yum install python-gevent
```

For some reason easy_install and pip do not work on gevent.